# Ubuntu Server on Laptop 22.04 becomes unresponsive when left alone

Tags: server, 22.04, crash

I have a 9th gen intel i9 Dell Precision laptop that I am running ubuntu server on.

I changed the lid settings so I could keep the lid closed and SSH into the machine.

I noticed that when I am actively using it, such as installing software or running commands it works just fine.

When I leave it alone, it seems like after 6-8 hours it just freezes. Totally unresponsive, SSH fails to connect and unresponsive when I try to used the laptop directly.

I watched the temp sensors with `watch sensors` command and nothing was over heating.

I ran a memtest and it passed with flying colors.

I went into the bios and disabled c states to see if that was the issue, and it did the same thing.

I can't seem to figure this out, any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

**Below is the log for when it crashes.**

```
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Updating lvfs
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 0%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 100%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: message repeated 2 times: [ Downloading…: 100%]
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 0%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 1%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 3%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 5%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 6%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 8%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 10%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 11%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 13%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 15%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 16%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 18%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 22%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 23%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 25%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 26%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 28%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 29%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 33%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 38%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 40%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 43%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 45%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 48%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 50%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 51%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 55%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 57%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 58%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 60%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 62%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 65%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 67%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 68%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 70%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 72%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 74%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 75%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 77%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 82%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 84%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 85%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 87%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 90%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 92%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 95%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Downloading…: 97%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Idle…: 100%
Nov  4 13:37:10 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Idle…: 100%
Nov  4 13:37:11 bethany fwupd[21149]: 13:37:11:0055 FuEngine             failed to get releases for UEFI dbx: No releases found: Not compatible with org.freedesktop.fwupd version 1.7.9, requires >= 1.9.1
Nov  4 13:37:11 bethany fwupd[21149]: 13:37:11:0199 FuEngine             failed to get releases for UEFI dbx: No releases found: Not compatible with org.freedesktop.fwupd version 1.7.9, requires >= 1.9.1
Nov  4 13:37:11 bethany fwupdmgr[21145]: Successfully downloaded new metadata: 2 local devices supported
Nov  4 13:37:11 bethany systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov  4 13:37:11 bethany systemd[1]: Finished Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
Nov  4 14:17:01 bethany CRON[30145]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

**Additional Details noticed when troubleshooting**

I noticed when it freezes that it is always stuck at the TTY1 screen.

If I SSH into the server and hit ctrl + alt + F1 then it becomes unresponsive, just as it is normally.

When I power it off and on, it automatically loads into TTY1 and I cannot enter login details unless I hit ctrl + alt + F2, then I can enter my username and password.

I am new to Ubuntu Server, is this expected behavior?
It seems like something about switching between TTy1 and TTY2 is causing it to freeze. Does a TTY session time out and then revert back to TTY1?

If I SSH and hit ctrl + alt + F1 then it becomes unresponsive just like before. I also noticed that when ever I open the laptop it is stuck at TTY1. So something about switching between TTY1 and TTY2 is causing it to crash. Is there a way around this? If I am on the laptop directly and switch back and forth it does not freeze.

**Update**

tried running `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` everything went smooth but as of 11/04/2023 8:15pm everything is frozen just as before. Entirely unresponsive.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Is the machine still *on* when it's unresponsive? Or does it shut itself off? There are some Dell (and HP) notebooks that take their UEFI power-saving settings pretty seriously when the OS does not override them. Ubuntu Server does not have all the packages required to work with notebook UEFIs to manage power as servers are generally left on all the time, so this could be something to look at.

Comment: it is on, but unresponsive. So if I open the lid it is stuck at the tty1 screen and ctrl + alt + F2 or any other combination doesn't work.  I also cannot SSH into the machine when this happens.

Comment: Is there anything written to `/var/log/syslog` around the suspected time of the system freeze? One possibility – assuming the notebook is using flash-based storage for the root file system – is that the storage device is entering a low-power mode and not recovering when action is being taken. If the `syslog` file shows zero messages between the suspected freeze and the subsequent forced boot, then this could be the issue. Generally I run Ubuntu Desktop and install the server packages whenever running a notebook as an always-on server, as it avoids these sorts of issues.

Comment: I actually fixed it. I reset the Bios to default settings, turned off C States and Intel Speed Step (I think it was called) and it has been running rock solid since 12 hours ago.

Comment: I thought I fixed it, then this morning it was frozen again. I am going to check the logs and see what I see @matigo.

Comment: I added the Log, nothing jumps out but I may also not know what I am looking for. @matigo I am probably going to reinstall with Ubuntu Desktop and install the Server Packages, unless you see something I am missing.

Comment: okay I noticed something, if I SSH and hit ctrl + alt + F1 then it becomes unresponsive just like before. I also noticed that when ever I open the laptop it is stuck at TTY1. So something about switching between TTY1 and TTY2 is causing it to crash. Is there a way around this? If I am on the laptop directly and switch back and forth it does not freeze.

Comment: I ran sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop and everything seemed fine. All of my configurations seemed to be preserved. However as of 1 hour ago everything is frozen just as before.

Comment: It may be better to simply install Ubuntu Desktop from the ISO and go from there. Dell machines often have additional packages that are downloaded during the installation process to handle things like power management and hardware-specific drivers. The server package will not have these for notebooks and installing `ubuntu-desktop` will not include the additional packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` as suggested by @matigo and then went back into bios and turned c-states back on and all of the intel power management. Once All of that was done, then everything worked as intended.

Really nice too, cause all of my power configurations with the lid states and everything I had already configured stayed that way. Super nice and easy, big win for Ubuntu.